# Tikz node positioning in math-environment especially \frac

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, positioning, nodes, labels

(this is my first TEX-question). I'm trying to label an equation within a tikzpicture. I did it this way:

```
\documentclass[15pt,a4paper,headinclude, totoc]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}       
\usepackage{tikz}                                               
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning}        
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}                                 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix[name=M3, matrix of nodes, inner sep=0pt, column sep=0pt]{
  \node (q) {$q$};
        & \node (eq1) {$=$};
        & \node (frac1) {$\dfrac{Q_l + Q_l^* + Q_f + Q_f^*}{2}$};
        & \node (eq2) {$=$};
        & \node (frac2) {$\dfrac{c(t) \cdot N(t)}{2 \cdot \lambda^2} \cdot$};
        & \node (end) {$\left[ \lambda-1+\lambda-1-\tau + \lambda + \lambda \cdot (1+\tau) \right]$};
        \\ };

    \node (Ql) [align=center, above=0.8em of frac1]{\footnotesize inland q-leader for inland};
\node (Ql*) [align=center, above right=1.8em of frac1] {\footnotesize inland q-follower at inland for inland q-leader};
    \node (Qf) [align=center, below=1em of frac1] {\footnotesize inland q-leader for foreign};
    \node (Qf*) [align=center, below right=1.8em of frac1] {\footnotesize inland q-follower for inland at foreign q-leader};

\draw[->] (Ql) -- (frac1);
\draw[->] (Ql*) -- (frac1);
    \draw[->] (Qf) -- (frac1);
    \draw[->] (Qf*) -- (frac1);

\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

This yields [image]

But I still don't know a way to adjust the arrow-labels to the designated Q's. I also tried some non-relative positioning like "from (1,-2) to (4.5,0.2);" but that's way to complicated.

Is there a way to designate the "Ql" in the frac to the Ql-label?

Thank you very much

Comment: I would use the tools of the `tikzmark` library. You could also put each part in its own node, but getting the spacing/positioning correct for all that math would be a nightmare.

Comment: And, of course: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) :-)

Comment: @PaulGessler You should provide an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach could be made shorter by using a `matrix of math nodes` which automatically sets each matrix element in math mode. But either way, that method results in suboptimal math spacing because you are relying on TikZ's matrix spacing rather than TeX's excellent math typesetting capabilities.

This would be my recommendation: I defined my own tweaked version of the `\tikzmark` macro found in the [library of the same name](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark):

```
\newcommand{\mytikzmark}[2]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,baseline,anchor=base] 
    \node (#1) {\ensuremath{#2}};}
```

Setting both `inner sep` and `outer sep` to `0pt` means that the spacing of the math is not affected by setting several terms of the equation into Tikz nodes.

The first argument is the node name that will be used to locate the node later. The second argument is the math content to typeset in the node (wrapped with `\ensuremath` just for convenience here).

Now, after the equation is finished (I used LaTeX's base displayed math, but this will work with any math environment), the node names can be referred to in a `tikzpicture`. This `tikzpicture` has the option `overlay` so that it has no size of its own and overprints other typeset content. For this reason, you'll need to add some vertical space in your document to make room for the Tikz content: otherwise it might overprint the nearby text.

Here's the full example. Of course, the positioning and other options in the `tikzpicture` can be adjusted to suit your needs. I've also used some options to the `tikzpicture` environment that reduce repetition in the code. For example `font=\footnotesize` sets the font for all node texts in that environment in one fell swoop. Same for the arrow specification `<-`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\mytikzmark}[2]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,baseline,anchor=base] 
    \node (#1) {\ensuremath{#2}};}

\begin{document}
\[ q 
  = \frac{\mytikzmark{Ql}{Q_l} + 
            \mytikzmark{Ql*}{Q_l^*} + 
            \mytikzmark{Qf}{Q_f} + 
            \mytikzmark{Qf*}{Q_f^*}}{2} 
  = \frac{c(t) \cdot N(t)}{2 \cdot \lambda^2} \cdot 
    \left[ \lambda-1+\lambda-1-\tau + \lambda + \lambda \cdot (1+\tau) \right]
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[<-,overlay,remember picture,inner sep=1.5pt,shorten <=0.2em,font=\footnotesize]
  \draw (Ql)  -- ++(1em,6.5em) node[right] {inland $q$-leader for inland};
  \draw (Ql*) -- ++(2em,5em)   node[right] {inland $q$-follower at inland for inland $q$-leader};
  \draw (Qf)  -- ++(3em,3.5em) node[right] {inland $q$-leader for foreign};
  \draw (Qf*) -- ++(4em,2em)   node[right] {inland $q$-follower for inland at foreign $q$-leader};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The example needs to be compiled twice, because the node locations are written to the `.aux` file and cannot be read and used for positioning the overlay until the second run.

Comment: Thanks. It's yet a bit difficult to understand the syntax of the "newcommand", but finally this looks very nice and I can copy-pase it in my code :)

Comment: @Mac I'm glad it works for you. Is there something you're wondering about the `\newcommand` that I can explain further?

Comment: Hello, not yet. I'll try to use this structure for other equations and see how far I can get :) thank you